# Возможно ли просуммировать переменные thymeleaf в JS?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Вот моя форма, очень хотелось бы, чтобы пользователь видел свою цену заказа до нажатия на submit.
Для этого нужно, чтобы каждый `${dish.price}` возле которого он нажал + ( input +1 ) просуммировался.
Как это реализовать? Вообще не понимаю, как для js мне достать переменную из лупа `th:each`.

```
   <form action="#" th:action="@{/menu}" th:object="${order}" method="post">

    <div th:each="dish : ${dishList}">
                    <div>
                        <h4 th:inline="text">[[${dish.name}]]<span class="price" th:text="${dish.price}">45</span></h4>
                        <p th:text="${dish.category}">DRINKS</p>
                        <p th:text="${dish.description}">
                            Aperiam tempore sit,perferendis numquam repudiandae porro
                            voluptate dicta saepe facilis.
                        </p>
                        <div>
                            <button class="decrement" type="button" onclick="stepperDecrement(this)">-</button>
                            <input
                                    th:value="0"
                                    th:name="${'dishIdQuantityMap[' + dish.id + ']'}"
                                    type="number"
                                    min="0"
                                    max="100"
                                    step="1"
                            />
                            <button class="increment" type="button" onclick="stepperIncrement(this)">+</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" value="Submit">Confirm order</button>

</form>
```

Вот мой JS ( просто +1 к `input type=number`, когда пользователь нажимает на кнопку + ).

```
function stepperDecrement(btn){
    const inputEl = btn.nextElementSibling;
    const calcStep =inputEl.step * -1;
    const newValue = parseInt(inputEl.value) + calcStep;
    if(newValue >= inputEl.min && newValue <= inputEl.max){
        inputEl.value = newValue;
    }
}
function stepperIncrement(btn){
    const inputEl = btn.previousElementSibling;
    const calcStep = inputEl.step * 1;
    const newValue = parseInt(inputEl.value) + calcStep;
    if(newValue >= inputEl.min && newValue <= inputEl.max){
        inputEl.value = newValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Почему вы поставbли тэг java?

Comment: вам надо разделить в голове фронтенд и бекенд. На бекенде вы готовите данные какие то и отправляете их в браузер. В браузере вы уже эти данные обрабатываете. Потому, если вам надо с бпекенда что то передать на фронт, у вас 2 варианта: 1) сразу на страничку поместить данные, например в какой то скрытый тег и на фронте его читать через js 2) выполнить асинхронный запрос в бекенд из браузера и получить данные. В вашем случае, вы генерируете разметку и читать вам надо данные из этой разметки.